# How do I create a rails setup where I can have a dev and production version of a javascript library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Something like Modernizr has both a developement and a production release of their library. How would I make this work with a rails setup? Is it just a matter of keeping both dev/prod versions available and then just using a simple `if (Rails.env.development?)` to switch on?

Or is there a fancier way?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the production version of JS libraries differs from dev only by being already minified.

You can either include dev libraries and let Rails asset pipeline minify them on its own during asset compilation, or just use production libraries everywhere at expense of ease of debugging said library code.